# AVPlayer doesn't play video

Tags: swift

I have a button ,when i press it i want to show a movie from the web.

this is my code :

```
@IBAction func trailersClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    let videoURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhD7hXrpExE")

    let player=AVPlayer(URL: videoURL!)

    let playerViewController=AVPlayerViewController()

    playerViewController.player=player

    self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) { ()->Void in
        playerViewController.player?.play()
    }

}
```

after the button was pressed i see the player but the movie doesn't play.
I have added the `App Transport Security Settings` with

```
Allow Arbitrary Loads
```

set to true.

Comment: I'm not sure that `AVPlayer` can play Youtube videos... I think that's where is your issue, not with ATS. Do a quick search on playing youtube videos on iOS with Swift.

Comment: actually i was using MPMoviePlayerController but because it is deprecated i wanted to change that @Larme

Comment: you are right,it doesn't play only youtube @Larme